How can I prevent mapping of null objects within an object using ModelMapper?
I'm using ModelMapper for object mapping in my Java application. However, I encountered an issue where null objects inside the source object are still being mapped to the destination object. How can I configure ModelMapper to skip mapping of null objects?
Here is my dto,
@Getter
@Setter
public class OperationDto extends BaseDto {
    private Long operationNo;
    private EnumOperationType operationType;
    private EnumOperationStatus operationStatus;
    private UserDto driverDto;
    private UserDto operatorDto;
    private VehicleDto vehicleDto;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Date targetDate;
    private LocationDto fromLocationDto;
    private LocationDto toLocationDto;
    private String description;


    @Override
    public Object newInstance() {
        OperationDto operationDto = new OperationDto();
        operationDto.setDriverDto(new UserDto());
        operationDto.setOperatorDto(new UserDto());
        operationDto.setVehicleDto(new VehicleDto());
        operationDto.setFromLocationDto(new LocationDto());
        operationDto.setToLocationDto(new LocationDto());
        return operationDto;
    }
}

and here is how I tried,
public List<OperationDto> getAllByFilter(OperationDto filterDto) throws TalyumException {
    OperationDto initializedFilterDto = (OperationDto) new OperationDto().newInstance();

    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);        
    initializedFilterDto = modelMapper.map(filterDto, OperationDto.class);

    List<OperationEntity> operationEntityList = operationRepository.findAllByFilter(initializedFilterDto);
    return operationEntityList.stream().map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, OperationDto.class)).toList();
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Could you try like this
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());

After you set this configuration, it should work, although I don't know exactly how you inject the model mapper in your code.

In ApplicationConfig.java I've defined model mapper like this.
code
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
return new ModelMapper();
}
code
And than imported in the service with the @AllArgsConstructor annotation;
code
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
code
Also, the solution doesn't work.
